# Extract the line by matching the word in a text file

Tags: python

I have one text file file which contains text. And other is csv file which contain designation. I want to extract the line where designation is match.

```
import nltk
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('textfile.txt', encoding='utf16') as f:
    sample = f.read()

file = pd.read_csv('designation.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)

data = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    des = df.loc[i]['Designations']
    for line in sample.splitlines():
        print(line)
        des_regex = r'[a-zA-Z]'+des+r'[a-zA-Z]'
        regular_expression = re.compile(des_regex, re.IGNORECASE)
        regex_result = (re.search(regular_expression, line))
        if regex_result:
            data.append(line)
```

Input text file:

> Sunder Pichai is the CEO of Google. Google is the american company
>   Google began in January 1996 as a research project by Larry Page and
>   Sergey Brin when they were both PhD students at Stanford University in
>   Stanford, California.[9]
>
> While conventional search engines ranked results by counting how many
>   times the search terms appeared on the page, the two theorized about a
>   better system that analyzed the relationships among websites.[10] They
>   called this new technology PageRank; it determined a website's
>   relevance by the number of pages, and the importance of those pages
>   that linked back to the original site.[11][12]
>
> Page and Brin originally nicknamed their new search engine "BackRub",
>   because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a
>   site.[13][14][15] Eventually, they changed the name to Google; the
>   name of the search engine originated from a misspelling of the word
>   "googol",[16][17] the number 1 followed by 100 zeros, which was picked
>   to signify that the search engine was intended to provide large
>   quantities of information.[18] Originally, Google ran under Stanford
>   University's website, with the domains google.stanford.edu[19] and
>   z.stanford.edu.[20]

Input csv file which contains designation:

```
CEO,
CTO,
COO
```

I want to output like:

```
Sunder Pichai is the CEO of Google
```

Comment: On what basis is the code to determine this desired output?

Comment: @ScottHunter  On the basis of line which i split from sample, if it is not fine  you can suggest me other method

Comment: What happens if the text is `The CEO of Google is Sundar Pichai` or `The CEO is John Doe`, or `The CEO of Google is, at the moment, Sundar Pichai`? In other words, how would you determine what text to pick and what to discard based on a single word?

Comment: It sounds like he just wants the sentences that the keyword occurs in.

Comment: " i want to extract the line where designatnation is match."

Comment: @chrisz - Those are not lines, technically speaking - the whole first paragraph is on a single line. The OP should first clarify what he's trying to achieve as it cannot be determined neither from his explanation nor from the posted code.

Comment: @chrisz you are right,  it's no matter either Sunder Pichai or John Doe, I just want to extract the line which contain CEO.

Comment: Do you mean line or sentence

Comment: @zwer Yes it all paragraph in one line so how can i get that only one line

Comment: I want to extract the sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *looks* like you want to divide the file into *sentences*, not lines.  The below code supports both, if you want to split into lines instead of files, simply replace `f.read().split('.')` with `f.read().splitlines()`

**`split`** your file into sentences:

```
with open('f1.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('.')
```

**`any`** and **`in`** to search each sentence

```
searches = ['CEO', 'CTO', 'COO']

for sentence in data:
    if any(i in sentence for i in searches):
        print(sentence)

# Result for your sample input file
Sunder Pichai is the CEO of Google
```

This does have some limitations, for example, sentences like:

> Dr. Strange is the CEO of Google
>
> The CEO of Google Inc. is Jared

Would not be read correctly, but hopefully this can get you started.